# How to start two ordered lists one right after the other in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

So, I want to have two numbered list one immediately after the other, but when I add new items to the second list with M-RET, or do anything else org-mode-ish in the vicinity of the lists, the second list gets renumbered as if part of the first one.

So, I want them to be:

```
1. first list, item one
2. first list, item two
1. second list, item one
2. second list, item two
```

How do I do that without "mangling" them when adding new items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the first list leave **two** blank lines - org-mode will then consider the first list to be complete, so the next list will be treated as a separate, new list.

e.g.,

```
1. first item
2. second item


1. first item of a second list
2. second item of the second list
```

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the numbering of an ordered list to whatever you want using a *number cookie*.

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
1. [@1] again item 1
2. item 2
```

Documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have a nested list ?

```
1. item 1
   1. sub item 1
   2. othe sub item
2. item 2
   1. sub item
      wow, on two lines !!!
   2. sub item 2
```

You can indent with M-